# Using GIS in Civil Engineering construction field?

Tags: road

I am thinking "How to use GIS when construction HighWays,Buildings,pipe lines etc?"

Is there any way we can utilize GIS for Civil Engineering construction industry to increase the efficiency of current construction work flows?

Any examples of using GIS in Civil Engineering construction field?

Comment: This is a huge topic. Can you try to narrow down the question so there is a definitive "right" answer?

Comment: I edited it.I want some kind of examples only.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly, have a look at the following link:

http://www.eepublishers.co.za/article/mobile-gis-for-construction-quality-managers-and-surveyors.html

Paper Title: 
Mobile GIS for construction quality managers and surveyors

Answer (score 1):

The Esri pages about "GIS for Architecture, Engineering and Construction (AEC)" have several examples, success stories, links to more case studies etc: http://www.esri.com/industries/civil_engineering/